# button in custom tableview cell not displaying

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and each cell is associated with a file.  The tableview shows files from all users and when the file for the cell belongs to the current user, the cell displays a edit button.  My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will check the userID associated with the file and compare it with the current users ID.  If the ID's match, the button is not hidden.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{

    let cell = self.fileTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FileCell
    let file = self.tableFiles[indexPath.row]
    cell.fileLabel.text = file.title
    cell.userLabel.text = file.username

    if file.userId != user?.userID
    {
        cell.editButton.hidden = true
    }

    cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(HomeController.editPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

This works fine when a user logs in and the tableview is loaded for the first time after login.  But when a user creates a new file to be added to the tableview `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` is called and the tableview reappears.  However, the edit button for the new file isn't being shown on the new file or any future added files unless the user logs out and logs back in.

Comment: Seems like you need to call the API once more to list the files as I don't see anywhere in your code where you might have saved the fileID of your newly created file.

Comment: When i pop back to the view controller containing the tableview, `viewWillAppear` calls the API to get the updated data.  I have print statements showing that the userID for the file and the current user do indeed match and a breakpoint set inside the if statement showing that the button isn't being hidden.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the cell being reusable. I had similar problem. Try  else cell.editButton.hidden = false. I think this will help. If it does I will post it in answers.

Comment: You might be right but why set it to false?  What will that accomplish?

Comment: I think it has some thing to do with dequeueReusableCell. Cell is reused again and does not update the subviews. So we are using else condition to forcefully update the subview which is cell.editButton.hidden = false in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should solve you problem.

```
if file.userId != user?.userID
{
    cell.editButton.hidden = true
}
else
{
    cell.editButton.hidden = false

}
```